# Animate.css transition only when website loads

Tags: html, css

For the transitions on one of my websites i use Animated.css.
It works just fine except when i apply a transition on the navbar, every time i change a page (clicking an item on the navbar), the transition runs again.

I would like to run the transition only when the website loads/reloads. Not when i change a page.

is there a way to accomplish that with plain css? Or do i need to implement some javascript code?

Snippet of the code:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div class="top-header animated fadeInDown">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-primary" role="navigation" id="navigation">
            //...
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework?

Comment: website reload vs page change?? what is the difference?

Comment: Agreed with @SagarKodte , when you change a page, you are loading it!

Comment: Tell me if what i understood is correct : You have a website of let's say 3 pages. P1, P2 and P3. You have an animation on P1 and it playes every time you come on P1. **PROBLEM :** You dont want this animation when coming from P2 or P3.  Am i correct ?

Comment: I do not think this can be done by css or javascript alone. (But I d like to see someone prove me wrong.) If you change a page it is the same as reloading usually. Unless you load all info on one page, then display it selectively (but you'd have to load a lot of data, making it a long wait). Or initiate some process that grabs some new information from a database and doesn't have to reload the entire page. None of them are worth the trouble just for a minor animation.

Comment: As others have said.... Depending on which page the user initially lands on - the first page they land on (may not be home) -  you would animate the nav just the once. So you need to track this, maybe set a cookie navWasAnimated.... And then read that back each page load to determine whether you should apply the class to the nav...

Comment: You can use `sessionStorage` to keep track that your animation has been run once for each session.

Comment: @SagarKodte, i know a reload and a page change does the same thing, but i was hoping that there was something slightly different where i could trigger on and thanks to that session-only cookie or sessionStorage there is. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a session-only cookie in javascript.

Include the following script at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
if (document.cookie.indexOf('siteloaded=loaded') < 0) {

    [... Activate Animation ...]

    document.cookie = "siteloaded=loaded";
}
</script>
```

When the site first loads, it will check to see if the session-only cookie exists.

If the cookie does not exist, it will activate the animation and set the cookie.

If the cookie exists, it will not activate the animation.

When the visitor closes the site tab, the session-only cookie is deleted.

---

**Additional Reading:**

Thanks to Mohit Bhardwaj for his tip, below.

If you want to try an HTML5 client-side-only storage solution which is more up-to-date and more powerful (faster performing, fewer server round-trips, greater capacity etc.) than using a session cookie, you might also check out the `window.sessionStorage` property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Isn't `sessionStorage` better and easier to use?